# Select only related entries for the model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-5

I'm completly stuck in how to get only the both related entries (teams) from a model (Match).

**Problem:**

The following code gets the correct match, **but all existing teams too**. A match only has **two** teams playing against each other and these are the both team I can't explicity get :-)

```
Match::with('teams')
    ->whereBetween('elo', [($request->user()->elo - 100), ($request->user()->elo + 100)])
    ->where('winner_id', 0)
    ->where('type', 'normal')
    ->get();
```

**Goal:**

I want get these two teams to assign a player to one of the both teams, after the match and teams got created. But if my tought are correct, it isn't save enough to just choose the both last entries!

1. create match (check)
2. create 2 teams (check)
3. assign players to one of the teams (stuck)

**Tables:**

Matches (id, winner_id, ...)
Teams (id, **match_id**, ...)
Players (id, user_id, **team_id**, ...)

**Relations:**

```
class Match extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'matches';

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
    }

    public function winner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'winner_id');
    }
}
```

Could you show me what is needed for that?

Comment: Please explain in terms of code what's the problem.  You are having problem on relationship?

Comment: I have a problem pointing out the right query in eloquentish to get the two teams assigned to a match.

Comment: Okay so what is the criteria for both of teams?

Comment: I mean you are selecting two teams on which basis?

Comment: just add where('match_id',YOUR_VALUE_HERE) and it will get you the team, what's the problem

Comment: @SherKhan Is it possible to check for where('match_id') when starting with Match::?

Comment: @ash at this point there is no need to distinguish the teams for me. I think. Teams are nameless. One is winner, one is looser :p

Comment: @Bensen I've cleaned up my comments - also after a quick read of your problem I'm a little bit confused.  In one part it sounds like your problem is that you can't get the `Team` records associated to a `Match` record, then your **goals** expresses a different problem about you being unable to relate the `Player` record to a `Team` record after a match.  Please could you explain the problem to make more sense.

Comment: I understand that, whoopsi!

Two teams are needed to assign a the players one for one. So the query needs to get the teams of a match. Still confusing? Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have told me in the comments of this post, a match will have multiple players and multiple teams (2) and that both the players and the teams *only* exist for/belong to a single match. With that in mind, you're looking at a set of fairly straightforward relationships/

**Match Model**

```
class Match extends Model {
    protected $table = 'matches';

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
     }

    public function winner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'winner_id');
    }
}
```

**Team Model**

```
class Team extends Model {
    protected $table = 'teams';

    public function match()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Match::class);
    }

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
    }
}
```

**Player Model**

```
class Player extends Model {
    protected $table = 'players';

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
     }
}
```

Now to assign a player to one of the teams (and therefore the match), you must use the [associate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) method. How you do it depends on what data you are starting out with. If you already know the team, you can just just do this:

```
$team = Team::find(123);
$player = Player::find(8734); //could also have created new Player here

$team->players()->associate($player);
```

If you do not know the team, but just know the match you can do this:

```
$match = Match::with('teams')->find(9003);
$team = $match->teams[0]; //choose teams[1] for second team, etc.
$player = Player::find(8734); //could also have created new Player here

$team->players()->associate($player);
```

You can always get all relevant data with this:

```
Match::with('teams.players')->find(9003);
```

This will return the Match data along with the teams who played in that specific match and the players who belong to that team.

Comment: Hello Sir. I forgot to explain that these "teams" are not like football teams. Every team will always be a group of 5 players with the same amount of points. So 1 team will only be part of 1 match.

Does this affect your last data query? Because it looks pretty nice, instead of mine :-)

Comment: So you're saying that one team only ever participates in one match? Can a player belong to multiple teams then?

Comment: No. It's really more like a yoga group that can change every time :D do you know a "moba game" where players get matched in teams?

Comment: But a player *could* play in more than one match, right? Or is it just one player and one team *only* per match, and all of them are completely new for each match? Just need to get the relationships totally clear before I revise my answer.

Comment: Every match everything totally new.

Comment: Okay, I will update my answer with the revised relationships.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my post. Let me know if that does what you're looking for! (and mind my note about the `match` relation on the Player model - that is technically not needed because you can always access the data through the Team model, but it is just a shortcut if you include a `match_id` on that table also)

Comment: Hey so I updated the post again. This time I show you how to assign players to one of the teams. Please let me know if this is what you want. If not, please let me know what you are still looking for.

Comment: Wowzers, so many useful functions! I just got a result with ur provided query for today and understood how to use the with()-thing :)

    `public function createPlayer($request)
    {
        $team = $this->findMatch($request);

        $player = new Player;
        $player->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $player->team_id = $team->id;
        $player->role = $request->role;
        $player->save();
    }`

but I wanna test and read about the associate function. Guess that will save some lines.